# Change of basis help?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

Find the change of basis matrices P(C<---B) and P(B<---C) for the basis B={1, x, x^2} and C = {1+x, x+x^2, 1+x^2} of P2. Then find the coordinate vector of p(x) = 1+2x-x^2 with respect to C.

Solution:

Changing to a standard basis is easy, so we find P(B<---C) first. Observe that the coordinate vectors for C in terms of B are

[1+x]B = [1,1,0] [x+x^2]B = [0,1,1] [1+x^2]B = [1,0,1]

These are column vectors not row vectors.

Then P(B<---C) = [a1,a2,a3] where a1=[1,1,0], a2= [0,1,1], and a3 =[1,0,1]. a1 represents column one and so on...

To find P(C<---B), we would express each vector in B as a linear combination of the vectors in C, but it is much easier to use the fact that P(C<---B) = the inverse of P(B<---C). We find that

P(C<---B) = [a1,a2,a3] where a1=[1/2,-1/2,1/2], a2= [1/2,1/2,-1/2], and a3 =[-1/2,1/2,1/2]. a1 represents column one and so on...**Where did they get this matrix from?**

They then multiplied that matrix by [p(x)]B which is the column matrix [1,2,-1] so that the final answer is the column matrix [2,0,-1]

Comment: You really should make an effort for learning how to properly write mathematics with LateX (MathJax) in this site (It's very easy...), otherwise your questions are going to be pretty difficult to understand and many people won't even try...

Comment: How do I get LateX?

Comment: I really don't know. Some time ago there was a FAQ section on the site where one could read about this, but some undisclosed genius decided to remove that section and we don't have it anymore...Perhaps in the "help" section in the upper part of the page...?

Comment: Okay let me google and try to figure it out

Comment: I tried researching... I have no idea how to fix it. I'm sorry.